# Typo in Learn you a Haskell for Great Good?

Tags: haskell, language-lawyer, partial-application, type-constructor

In [Type Synonyms](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#type-synonyms) we read

> Just like we can partially apply functions to get new functions, we can partially apply *type parameters* and get new type constructors from them.

How can a *parameter* **be applied to** something else? I think it should actually be

> Just like we can partially apply functions to get new functions, we can partially apply *type constructor (giving them less type parameters then they expect)* and get new type constructors from them.

Do you agree?

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Not agree cos of this: `type AssocList k v = [(k,v)]`

Comment: This is a discussion-based question, a better fit for /r/haskell

Comment: @MichaelLitchard, can you explain the rational behind your statement? What does make this quesion opinion-based?

Comment: I disagree, because it is informally accepted to say eg. "apply the arguments to the function" and their usage is a valid extension of this.

Comment: _Fewer_ type parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author seems to use *apply* to mean both "the function to the parameters" as well as "the parameters to the function".

Further down we read

> we'll partially apply Either by feeding it only one parameter

Where the meaning is the former,
as well as

> Let's apply the type parameter to Maybe and see what the kind of that type is.

```
ghci> :k Maybe Int
```

where the meaning is the latter.

Comment: From my non-native English perspective the former and the latter are both correct as much as `Int -> Char` and `Char -> Int` are the same type, hence the question. It seems that my non-English-ness fooled me, thus making the question opinion-based.